# Optimize Query with multiple function calls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view that calls multiple functions within. The execution time is around 1.5 minutes. How can I optimize my execution time Without replacing the Function Calls with CASE WHEN's (which isn't really possible in most of them)

```sql
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[PersonData] (PersID,
                                PersonalNr,
                                LastName,
                                FirstName,
                                DateEntCompany,
                                DateLeftAC,
                                Company,
                                Plant,
                                Department,
                                BadgeNr,
                                AccessProfileName)
AS
    SELECT hPerson.PersID,
           hPerson.PersonalNr,
           hPerson.LastName,
           ISNULL(hPerson.FirstName, ''),
           dbo.fnKSS_GetDateEntCompany(hPerson.DateEntCompany),
           dbo.fnKSS_GetDateLeftAC(hPerson.DateLeftAC),
           ISNULL(PersonFreeField.Text1, ''),
           ISNULL(PersonFreeField.Text2, ''),
           ISNULL(PersonFreeField.Text3, ''),
           ISNULL(dbo.fnKSS_GetLeastBadgeNrOfPerson(hPerson.PersID), ''),
           ISNULL(dbo.fnKSS_GetAccessProfileOfPerson(hPerson.PersID), '')
    FROM [Person].dbo.hPerson hPerson
         INNER JOIN [Person].dbo.hPersonClient PersonFreeField ON PersonFreeField.PersFK = hPerson.PersID
    WHERE dbo.fnKSS_GetAccessProfileOfPerson(hPerson.PersID) IS NOT NULL -- only transfer person with access profile
      AND dbo.fnKSS_GetLeastBadgeNrOfPerson(hPerson.PersID) IS NOT NULL; -- only transfer person with badge
```

Comment: Rewrite your scalar functions to be table-valued functions.

Comment: I doubt that applying a [user defined scalar] `FUNCTION` on your column in the `WHERE` will be SARGable either.

Comment: What does your function do, what is its definition? And the definition of the relevant tables and indexes. Please also share a query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2019 had a new optimization called function inligning that can solve some counterperformances when using scalar UDF.

But think that UDF has an iterative way of execution that SQL does it by sets...
So try to not uses scalar UDF...